# Modify Metadata from inside of an Interceptor

Tags: nestjs

I would like to dynamically set the SerializeOptions of a controller method, depending on the role of a user when using NestJS.

I created an Interceptor and got the role with

```
intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {
  const role = context.switchToHttp().getRequest().user?.role;

  // set SerializeOptions({groups: [role]}) somehow

  return next.handle();
}
```

I've learned that setting the metadata `class_serializer:options` to `{groups: [role]}` works as well, but I could not find a way to dynamically modify the metadata of the controller method inside of an interceptor.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure this is a right way to handle this matter or not, but it works for me.

```
import {
  CallHandler,
  ClassSerializerContextOptions,
  ExecutionContext,
  Injectable,
  NestInterceptor,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { map, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { instanceToPlain } from 'class-transformer';

@Injectable()
export class YourCustomClassSerializerInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {
    const defaultGroups = [];
    const  groups  = context.switchToHttp().getRequest().user?.role;

    const options: ClassSerializerContextOptions = { groups: defaultGroups };
    return next.handle().pipe(map((value) => instanceToPlain(value, options)));
  }
}
```

your controller result object must contain an instance of a entity object.

like:

```
{
  total: 0,
  limit: 5,
  data: [Post, Post]
}
--- OR ---

new Post()
```